# Getting the actual type from reflection fieldInfo

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, casting, fieldtype

I'm writing a generic wrapper around a software's GUI API which has the ability to process quite a few of its own 'built-in' types but I can't figure out how to get it what it needs. For example, I'm doing this to handle strings:

*("MakeTextField" and "MakeField" are pseudo-code, which take a value, display a GUI element and then return the value from the GUI for storage)*

```cs
public static void FieldInfoMakeField<T>(T instance, System.Reflection.FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    string label = fieldInfo.Name;

    if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(string))
    {
        var val = (string)fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
        val = MakeTextField(label, val);
        fieldInfo.SetValue(instance, val);
        return;
    }
    //else if ... more types
```

This is what I have for the API's type where A and B are derrived from a common type, which I can also test for, but I need the derrived type:

```cs
...
else if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(APITypeA))
{
    var val = (APITypeA)fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
    val = MakeField<APITypeA>(label, val);  // My version, casts internally
    fieldInfo.SetValue(APITypeA, val);
    return;
}
else if (fieldInfo.FieldType == typeof(APITypeB))
{
    var val = (APITypeB)fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
    val = MakeField<APITypeB>(label, val);  // My version, casts internally
    fieldInfo.SetValue(APITypeB, val);
    return;
}
...
```

This all works, but I have about 10 more copy&paste code blocks for other "APITypes". If I wasn't doing this generically, I would just pass in any type derived from the API's base type and it would work, but I can't figure out how to get the fieldInfo's actual type. If I print it, it will print the name of the derived types, but I can't seem to get them out.

I hope I'm stating my problem well enough. This is highly situational but seems like it should be possible. If I could just get the type that FieldType() prints, I would be gold. Otherwise I have #regions full of else if statements, which certainly isn't as generic as I would like!

Comment: You might want to replace one of these tags with [tag:c#] so the language is clear. That will probably get the post more views anyway.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're after, but perhaps the C# [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(v=VS.100).aspx) keyword could be of use?

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to provide the `Type` of the field to the `FieldInfoMakeField` function?

```
public static void FieldInfoMakeField<T, V>(T instance, FieldInfo fieldInfo)
{
    string label = fieldInfo.Name;

    var val = (V)fieldInfo.GetValue(instance);
    val = MakeField<V>(label, val);
    fieldInfo.SetValue(instance, val);
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything beforehand, only that I am starting with a serialized object. I am iterating through all public fields and creating GUI controls for them. So I need to detect the type to run the right GUI static method from this API I'm wrapping. I can do this one by one, but I can't get the actual type as a variable I can pass to one of the methods which can take more than one type, so I have to add a ton of extra else-if blocks which all run the same method. 

Interesting pattern though...This is aside from the OP, but can more than one be constrained?

Comment: If you mean can more than one type be constrained, the answer is yes - `public static void FieldInfoMakeField<T, V>(T instance, FieldInfo fieldInfo) where T : new() where V : new()`